# Put contour plots of for non-overlapping data ranges on a single set of axes?

Tags: matlab, contourf

I would like to put contour plots of two datasets on the same axes with the same colorbar. The X and Y ranges of the data do not overlap but are physically adjacent.

Here's a simplified example of two such contourf plots which I'd like to combine on the same axes:

```
   %generate 1st sample dataset
   [x1,y1]=meshgrid(-3:3);
   v1=peaks(x1,y1)

   %generate 2nd sample dataset & move it so it is physically adjacent to 
   %1st dataset
   [x2,y2]=meshgrid(-4:4);
   v2=peaks(x2,y2)
   x2=8+x2;

   figure(1)
   contourf(x1,y1,v1)
   colormap(jet)
   colorbar('EastOutside')
   xlabel('x (mm)')
   ylabel('y (mm)')

   figure(2)
   contourf(x2,y2,v2)
   colormap(jet)
   colorbar('EastOutside')
   xlabel('x (mm)')
   ylabel('y (mm)')
```

This produces the following plots

[image]
[image]

I tried to put the two sample datasets on the same axes using the following:

```
    figure(3)
    contourf(x1,y1,v1)
    colormap(jet)
    hold on

   contourf(x2,y2,v2)
   colormap(jet)
   hold off
```

Using the typical "hold on" didn't work... suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

The second contour plot is invisible as the x axis limits are too small. Add the following commands to your script after `hold off`

```
xlim([-3 12]);
ylim([-4 4]);
```

This will produce the following plot

[image: Plot]